# Low voltage when using remote starter

Tags: battery, starting, starter, remote-start, voltage

Recently, I have been unable to remote start my 2003 Honda Accord Coupe.  I brought the car to an auto-zone, and they told me (after hooking my battery up to a voltage tester) that I had "low voltage" when remote starting, but my battery was completely healthy.

What steps should I take to investigate this further?  Could it simply be the wire to the remote starter is too frayed?

[Two images of the battery with remote starter cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a31D.jpg)

[Video of car not starting with remote starter](https://vid.me/8ELM)

Comment: Does the same issue exist when you start the car normally, with a key in the ignition?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think the 03 Accord came with remote start from the factory did it?  Is it aftermarket remote start?

Comment: @charlieRB it works great with the key, there is only a problem with the remote start.

Comment: That is correct, an aftermarket Prestige remote start system was installed.

Comment: I added photos and videos

Comment: Regardless of what is powered by that frayed wire, it needs to be repaired. The entire connection looks as though it needs some attention. If you cannot repair it, have a mechanic fix it for you.

Answer (score 2):

A frayed wire could definitely be the cause. What is the, "wire to the remote starter" and what is it's function?

Starting a car, remotely or otherwise, requires a large wire to provide power from the battery to the starter motor, usually through a relay. If you have a bad connection such as wire that's not large enough, wire that is damaged or frayed, or corrosion, the starter motor won't be able to get enough power from the battery and it will struggle to start the car.

It sounds like the full power from the battery isn't getting through to the starter motor. Does this happen when turning the car over with the key? I'd be curious to know more about how the remote starter is integrated into the car's existing starting circuit.

Comment: I added two photos of the frayed wire, and a video of the car not starting. 

the car starts wonderfully when the key is in the ignition.

Comment: When I use the key, it turns over once it twice and starts immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Remote start is not a separate starting system. It is an electronic control that triggers the existing system to start the engine. Since your car starts by key without issue, I suspect the problem you are having is not related to the car battery or starter itself.

Likely what is happening is the battery in your remote is low or dead causing no signal. Before you start chasing wires, change the battery in the remote first.

Comment: The battery was low when this problem started, and the remoted indicateed that.  I just replaced it with a new Duracell battery and the remote shows a full charge.  The problem persists though.

Comment: I uploaded a video of the car not starting and two photos of the battery connection to the remote starter.  Maybe that would help?